Qt: virtual slots disconnect
I have such code example
#include <QAbstractItemModel>
QAbstractItemModel* pSomeModel;

class A : public QObject
{

public:

    A(){
        connect(pSomeModel, &QAbstractItemModel::dataChanged, this, &A::foo); 
    }

protected slots:
    virtual void foo(){};
};

class B : public A
{

public:
    B(){}

    void disconnectFoo() // calls for some extra reasons, when i do not need to accept model signals
 {
        disconnect(pSomeModel, &QAbstractItemModel::dataChanged, this, &A::foo); // cannot access protected member error
 };

protected slots:
    void foo() override {};
};

I've read some information about this problem and get that's I can access only for protected member B::foo inside B. So I've tried to disconnect(pSomeModel, &QAbstractItemModel::dataChanged, this, &B::foo);, but of course it doesn't work correct, because it still call A::foo slot for model signal.
I can disconnect(model, signal, A, nullptr) and then connect(model, signal, B, foo) and it's works correct, but it looks ugly. And It works only for such case with only one virtual slots, but what if I need some slots and don't need to disconnect them. So how to properly disconnect such virtual slots?

Save the QMetaObject::Connection returned by QObject::connect and pass that to QObject::disconnect?

It's a good idea, but I cannot connect exactly same connection then. I will need to write smth like connect(model, signal, B, &B::foo), cause i haven't access to A::foo. So it's a little bit strange. There doesn't seem to be a method, to do it in my way. Apparently I will need to make slot public or disconnect slot A::foo and connect B::foo.

connection is a metaclass representing abstract concept. there is one or more of them (you can connect two things several times, then single signal fires slot more than once) but identity of connection is fully defined by what you connect. If you disconnect it last time, it's gone. absense of access later is why you have to do parenting or operate connections from outside. Also, if you had Q_OBJECT macro, you can find every instance of the class. And if you wish, you can give them individual names.

To be honest, I don't understand how this will help me solve the problem. I have provided an example of the code, sure it's not ideal. It doesn't have virtual dtor's and q_object macro, but it can be compiled and clearly identify the problem. And I don't get how understanding of connection meta essence could help me?

protected slots are for class it is used in or for friends . It was your choice to make them protected. Ofc you can do it command-pattern way and have a method in A. That's arguably uglier but functional. Btw, not everything that can be compiled can work. Especially in Qt where incorrect use often even can run without errors, just do nothing. That's their design choice.

The code is contradicting Qt's paradigms. No Q_OBJECT macro in class definition while you're in need of metaobject functionality is a major one. Without it these classes are just QObjects to Qt and not themselves.
Unparented objects and global variable pointing(or not?) to some object is another. You had tied their implementation to global variable which is a bad design for both OOP and functional paradigms.
Qt wouldn't delete orphans and you should take care and use deleteLater() method on them because they are connected.
You cannot connect non-public slots from other class, that's by design. They must be public or have a way to provide access to their address.
External connection procedure is actually a common happenstance, it serves as a decoupling mechanism: no circular dependencies between classes this way. Connecting to a child object from inside of parent object is another.
E.g. model can be a parent of these two and they connect and do other unmentionables to her.
